# How to set a background color for a composite which is inside another composite?

Tags: swt, eclipse-rcp

I Have created two buttons which is inside a composite B which inturns inside the Composite A.

Composites are  created by using form toolkit.

```
     Composite compositeA= toolkit.createComposite(form.getBody(),  SWT.WRAP);

     Composite compositeB= toolkit.createComposite(compositeA,  SWT.WRAP);
```

I have set both composite A and composite B to

```
    compositeA.setBackgroundMode(SWT.INHERIT_FORCE);
    compositeB.setBackgroundMode(SWT.INHERIT_FORCE);

    compositeB.setBackground(new Color(display, 215,226,252) );
```

But when i try to set background color of CompositeB  it is not working .

Any Advice?

Comment: If I do it standalone (without the form toolkit) it works for me. Could you provide a complete example? And why do you set `SWT.INHERIT_FORCE`? It says: "The Composite constant to indicate that an attribute (such as background) is inherited by all children."

Comment: @FranzBecker : Its not working for me because i need to add toolkit.adapt(compositeB) before using the setBackground.

Comment: I think you should call `setBackground()` on compositeA to propagate it to compositeB.